# Как поставить курсор в конец inputa в Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

Кто-нибудь знает как это сделать в Chrome?

Все, что нашла в инете - для IE+.

Comment: может тебе нужно чтобы текст набирался с правой стороны?
text-align:right

Answer (score 6):

Поможет функция `setSelectionRange()`

Например есть:

```
<input id="edt" type="text" value="12345" />
```

Чтобы установить курсор в конец строки нужно:

```
var el=document.getElementById('edt');
el.focus();
el.setSelectionRange(el.value.length,el.value.length);
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/KiTE/C95c2/)

Comment: вы дали ссылку на пример..
но там сразу же видно что курсор все равно в начале инпута стоит..

или я что-то не понимаю..

Comment: @Анна, в примере, установка курсора в конец подвешена на нажатие кнопки "Установить курсор в конец строки поля ввода".

Answer (score 3):

- [Set Cursor Position in Text Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area)
- [Рабочее решение со StackOverflow](http://jsfiddle.net/gridsane/cNqbD/1/)

Если нужен чистый js - там ничего сложного.

```
<input type=text id='input_' value="xxcxcxcx"/>
<input type="button" value="Кнопка" id="btn" />​
```

--

```
$.fn.setCursorPosition = function(pos) {
    this.each(function(index, elem) {
    if (elem.setSelectionRange) {
        elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
    } else if (elem.createTextRange) {
        var range = elem.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', pos);
        range.moveStart('character', pos);
        range.select();
    }
    });
    return this;
};
$("#btn").click(function () {
    var input = $("#input_");
    input.setCursorPosition(input.val().length);
});
```

​